# UIView not autoresizing when the superView frameWidth changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

So I have a UIView called footerView which is added to a UIScrollView. I've initialize it as follows:

```
 UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView_.frameWidth, kFooterViewHeight)];
    [footerView setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
    [footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 self.footerView_ = footerView;
    [self.scrollView_ setFooterView_:self.footerView_];
    [footerView release];
```

So initially the scrollView.frameWidth is set to 768. But then at later point it is adjusted to 450. After this happens I tried checking self.footerView.frameWidth and it's still at 768. Why is this?
 I've tried calling setNeedsLayout on footerView, I made sure that auto-resize views is set on the UIScrollView, but nothing happens.

Comment: OK - I'm confused. What is this footerView? Its a subview of the scrollView contentView? The contentView would not get resized when you resize the scrollView.

Comment: yes, it's a subview of the scrollView. Really? The contentView is not resized? How do I make the contentView to resize as the width of the UIScrollView

Comment: Your code is hard to read with that _ at the end of objects *and* methods. Can't you simply use `@synthezise scrollView = _scrollView;`, then you don't need to write self.scrollView anymore. And can you try a `[_scrollView addSubView:_footerView];` instead of assigning it to an object?

Comment: Yes, you want to `addSubview` for any resizing to take place. Where are you doing that? And you probably only want `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`.

Comment: And I notice that you're footerview has an origin of 0,0. How would that work for a footer? I'd expect to see a y coordinate of something like `self.view.frame.size.height - kFooterViewHeight`. Or are you adding it to some container UIView that you added via Interface Builder or something like that. In that case, does that have it's `autoresizingMask` set properly, too? All of the views throughout the view hierarchy (the footer view, its container, the scrollview, etc.) need to have the autoresizingMask set accordingly (either programmatically or through IB, as appropriate).

Comment: Check `scrollView.autoresizesSubviews`. It's complicated since it's a scroll view; you may have to subclass it and do the layout manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setting both, flexible margins and flexible width. If you want, that the view resizes, avoid the flexible margins.

Comment: I did that and it didn't change